# BLE Device dissonect after receive Notifications (BLEGattException Status = 0x8)

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-ble, rxandroidble

My BLE server permanently measures a sensor value and sends a notification with 20 byte user data after each measurement. The goal is to generate as much throughput as possible.

On the client side, the value sent by the server is received and processed.

```
rxBleConnection.setupNotification(setDescriptorEnableNotification(characteristic))
                .flatMap(notificationObservable -> notificationObservable)
                .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .buffer(1)
                .subscribe(bytes -> {
                            onNotificationReceived(bytes, buffer);
                        } , throwable -> {
                            // Handle an error here.
                            onNotificationSetupFailure(throwable);
                        }

                );
```

If I set the Connection intervall to 11.25ms, I receive all values. However, if I set the connection interval to 30ms, I receive a few values ​​and then the connection is closed.

In the Android Log i see the followed message:

> BleGattException status=8 (0x8),
> bleGattOperationType=BleGattOperation{description='CONNECTION_STATE'

**Why is the connection interrupted and what is the trigger?**

With the help of a BLE Sniffer this is not recognizable. The set connection parameters are accepted and the transfer begins. Suddenly the transmission ends and the error message appears.

**Update:**
BLE Sniffer screenshot has been added:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

30ms, this is connection interval you set in server or android?

Btw, on android you can set speed mode

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    mBluetoothGatt.requestConnectionPriority(BluetoothGatt.CONNECTION_PRIORITY_HIGH);
}
```

Comment: The 30ms intervall I set on server side. I use a Arduino 101 with CurieBLE

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, you have min connection interval 7.5 on your BLE kit, but now it is deprecated on Android.
Try to set min connection interval to 11.25 on your BLE kit and set connection priority

gatt.requestConnectionPriority(CONNECTION_PRIORITY_HIGH);

where CONNECTION_PRIORITY_HIGH = 1

in onConnectionStateChange.
It had worked for me when I had changed min connection interval in my nordic from 7.5 to 11.25.

Answer (score 0):

Error 8 means the connection timed out. There is nothing wrong on the Android side. The problem is with the communication between the two Bluetooth controllers. If you have a sniffer then you should be able to see who is the one that fails to send packets.

Comment: With the sniffer nothing can be seen.However, the "More Data" flag is set to true. The following message has the flag "Sequence Number = False"

Comment: You should post the sniffer log on the peripheral's chip's manufacturer support forum to get a good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Image from BLE Sniffer.

[BLE Sniffer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eC5fs.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar problem. On Android 7.0 there were two ways to keep connection:

1) If devices are bonded and there is a charachteristic reading callback with constant thread of packets. If there are no packets by some time, then connection fails.

2) If devides are not bonded, but I do TXCharacheristic.read every few seconds. If don't do that some time, then connection fails.

But now in Android 7.1.2 this way doesn't work. 
May be the first way will work for you.
On your Android device you should make bonding, on your kit you should handle this bonding.
On Nexus 6P and Samsung S7 it doesn't work anymore, but I didn't try it on the other devices.